# How to hide reputation label in experience/Community cloud

Tags: community, experience-cloud

Is there any way to hide `reputation label` and `reputation points` for internal employee in Salesforce Experience cloud?
There is a setting to hide it for all employee but I want to display the labels and points only for community users, not for internal employees.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding audience on "Reputation LeaderBoard" component. I guess you can make it visible only for community users by adding specific audience to this component. This way you can control display of reputation.